# Best and fastest way to store sensor data in C# UWP app

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp

I have a custom sensor, connected via Bluetooth, that streams data to my UWP app.
I need to store this data locally somehow, however my problem is that it is streaming at 100Hz, so the data is arriving at the app very quickly.

I have tried to store the data into a SQLite database, as it will be easier to work with the data later. e.g. searching the data.
However the SQLite database cannot keep up with the data stream and starts to lag behind considerably overtime.

So does anyone have any advice or recommendations to the best approach for storing large amounts of data very quickly in C# UWP apps?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: What does the structure of your data look like, is it a simple timestamp-value sample or does it include things such as GPS coordinates and other details per sample?

Comment: The structure is timestamp, x,y,z (acceleration data), and several other generic fields (Strings and Boolean).
Sorry forgot to mention the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store data in file instead of sqlite, just append data to file each time. You can use csv or tab separated format. for improving performance save data in batches.

create two array of objects.
imported data will be added to one array.
once array is full save that array and new input will be added to other array. you should continues switch between them when one of them is full. and save them(it is like two buffer)

Comment: I think I will go with a csv file for storage and just use the database to store the references to the csv files.
I like the idea of using two buffers, which means I could run the data saving on another thread once one of the buffers is full.
Thanks for the advice :)